# $x^{1/k}$ is a strictly decreasing function in $k$

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Terence Tao, ***Analysis I***, 3e:

> **Lemma 5.6.6.** Let $x,y \ge 0$ be non-negative reals, and let $n,m \ge 1$ be positive integers.
>
> ...
>
> (d) We have $x > y$ if and only if $x^{1/n} > y^{1/n}$.
>
> (e) If $x > 1$, then $x^{1/k}$ is a decreasing function of $k$. (...)

Exercise 5.6.1 requires the reader to prove lemma 5.6.6.e (amongst others). The following is my attempt to do so.

By definition, $x^{1/k} := \sup \{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y \ge 0 \; \wedge \; y^k \le x \}.$

If $x > 1$, then $x^{1/k} > 1$ (proof skipped) and

$$
\tag{1}\label{eqn.lubLargerOne}
\sup \{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y \ge 0 \; \wedge \; y^{k + 1} \le x \} > 1.
$$

Since the least upper bound is greater than $1$, there is an element greater than $1$ in the set. Otherwise, if all elements were less than $1$ or equal to $1$, there would always be an upper bound less than the least upper bound. A contradiction.

Hence, for all $y > 1$, and $x' := xy^{-1}$,

$$
\tag{2}\label{eqn.normalization}
y^{k+1} = y^k y \le x \Rightarrow y^k \le x' < x
$$

such that $x > 1$ implies

$$
\tag{3}\label{eqn.identity}
\sup \{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y \ge 0 \; \wedge \; y^{k + 1} \le x \}
=
\sup \{ y \in \mathbb{R}: y \ge 0 \; \wedge \; y^k \le x' \}.
$$

From 5.6.6.d:

$$
\tag{4}\label{eqn.conclusion}
x > x' \Rightarrow x^{1/k} > (x')^{1/k} = x^{1/(k+1)},
$$

which requires that $x^{1/k}$ is a decreasing function of $k$.

Correct?

Comment: Your proof is correct but it seems like there should be a more elementary approach.